# Fix UDP issues on subnet

Tags: subnet, udp

I currently have a network with the following topography: [topography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8chSN.png)

Networking is fine and all works well, except for one thing: UDP seems to be unstable/not working on the subnets 192.168.3 and 192.168.4.0. The way that these subnets are setup is that my Windows Server instance has two (virtual) NIC's that act as gateways for their designated subnets. These subnets are statically routed in dd-wrt like this:
[static routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo92n.png).

I cannot seem to be able to figure out why UDP is so unreliable on these subnets while it works just fine on the main net (192.168.2).

Any help or explanation as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

For anyone wondering, this is the result of [packetlosstest](https://packetlosstest.com), as can be seen in the image, as soon as it has sent 50 packets, all subsequent traffic is cut off: [image]

Comment: Could you explain more detailed what exactly you mean with „unstable / not working “?

Comment: @Martin Ok so, the way I tested this was as following, I setup a continuous ping to 8.8.8.8 on a machine that's on the 192.168.4 subnet. Then I setup a OpenVPN connection. At first I set the configuration to TCP only. This results in expected behaviour: the packets are dropped during the connecting phase but the ping will continue running normally once connected. However, when I select UDP it starts going wrong. Again packets are dropped when I connect. After that I manage to consistently receive 4 packets before the ping starts to timeout. This behaviour is also seen in UDP based games.

Comment: The behavior in your comment sounds exactly normal. TCP will adjust transmission to network congestion, but UDP has no way to do that.

Comment: @RonMaupin Ok, but how would I make it work consistently though? Clearly the way that UDP seems to be behaving now is very undesirable.

Comment: The problem is that your incoming bandwidth is already used by the time you see the traffic, TCP being dropped due to congestion will slow the TCP transmission, but you simply cannot do that with UDP. You could try to get more bandwidth, or you will need to work with your upstream provider to drop UDP before it reaches you. In any case, I'm not sure why you allow employees to play games on your business network. You could try to block gaming.

Comment: Are you sure that this is not an openvpn configuration error? I doubt that this is due to network congestion... if some packets get lost, this would be an explanation, but not for 100% packet loss.

Comment: @RonMaupin So I ran this test on a device on my subnet and a device on my normal net: packetlosstest.com and I found some interesting behaviour. The device on my normal net works as you would expect, it drops 0 to 2 packets at worst. However, when I run this test on my subnet'ed device, all packets after 48/50 are dropped. What's even stranger is that this seems to be connected to the rate at which packets are sent. At very high speeds (50 pings/s) all packets are received. But at somewhere around 20 pings/s the previously described behaviour is observed.

Comment: @Martin It is not, read my comment above.

Comment: This sounds like a NAT issue... as if the windows Server forgets the nat translation too fast...

Comment: @Martin Any idea about how I would check if this is the case or not? Also would it be the fault of the router or Windows Server, considering that the static routing is managed through the router.

Answer (score 0):

The static routing is okay - otherwise the TCP testcase wouldn't work. What I meant was the dynamic routing:

- client 192.168.4.111 sends a UDP packet to 8.8.8.8
- on the windows server, the source ip is translated to 192.168.2.2, and a dynamic source port is assigned.
- any response on that port is routed back to the client.

This process is called masquerading - and such a dynamic route has a timeout - if no response is received on that source port for a certain amount of time, the dynamic port is closed. Usually, this timeout setting is configurable. And: This timeout setting is different to TCP, since UDP doesn't know any connections. I do not know where to setup this timeout on windows ...
If I were you, I would install wireshark on your windows server. If your wireshark sees a response which is not received by your client, you know that this timeout is the cause.

Comment: Hey Martin, I did some more testing and unfortunately my assertion about it not disconnecting when the packets are sent fast enough wasn't true. It seems that around 1 out of the 5 tests I run completes successfully. I tried playing around with the UDP timeout limits on my router as well (unfortunately to no avail). I should also note that my Windows Server isn't actually doing the routing itself, it is simply a host for the subnet gateway NICs.

Comment: your dd-wrt router is not the cause... I am pretty sure the reason must be hidden somewhere in your windows server, because otherwise these issues would appear on the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet, too!

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that the server instance runs on a VM, so the internet connection for the server and those two (virtual) NIC's get pushed over one line. Do you think that that might cause the issue?